# Rails get the parent from the AR relation of a has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model `Client` which `has_many :analytics` and `Analytic` which `belongs_to :client`. I have written a method in the analytic model to update itself for a given client and basically want to call `Client.find(xx).analytics.update_analytics(arg1, arg2,..)`

The code in `Analytic.rb` looks something like this:

```
def self.update_analytics(arg1, arg2, ...)
  client = self.client
  //go_get_some_data
  client.analytics.create(...)
end
```

The `self.client` errors out `undefined method` and `self.parent` just returns `Object` but I cannot call `self.parent.id` or other attributes from the parent.

How do I get the `Client` instance that called the `analytics.update_analytics` method inside of it?

Comment: Why do you need Client instance ?

Comment: because in the method I create analytics objects in the DB and need the right foreign key to make sure they are associated with the right client.

Answer (score 0):

A method prefixed with self is a class method, you need an instance method in the Analytic model

```
def update_analytics
  self.client # this should already be set or you would never be able to loop through a client's analytics. when creating analytics you should be assigning the client_id prior to calling this method or it would never work
end
```

Also, you will need to loop through all the analytics that belong to Client and call the update_analytics method on each object

```
@client = Client.find(xx)
@client.analytics.each do |analytic|
  analytic.update_analytics(arg1, arg2,..)
end
```

Comment: I want it to be a class method though because it goes out, get some data an then creates new instances of itself (and saves them to the DB)

Comment: a class method is not acted upon an instance of an analytic object so you wouldnt be able to set a row's client_id in that manner which is why it would need to be an instance method to assign an object/row's client_id attribute

Comment: there is no need to loop through anything because the method has a `self.create(...)` line in it. Basically the method is meant to go out, grab data and create a whole bunch of analytics objects in the DB for the Client that calls it. Now it makes sense for me to put that method in the analytics class as a class method, doesn't it?

Comment: As other users have commented, Client.find(xx).analytics will return a collection/array, you can't call a method on that collection, you will need to call an instance method on an individual object of the collection which is why in your scenario you would need to iterate through the collection and call instance method on each object of collection. Please see http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/ and other links to understand the usage of class vs instance methods

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
Client.find(xx).analytics
```

Under the hood it will be:

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id = xx
SELECT * FROM analytics WHERE client_id = xx
```

Actually the line:

```
 Client.find(xx).analytics.update_analytics(arg1, arg2,..)
```

Will not work, because `.analytics` returns array of analytics. So you must iterate over them and call some method.

Comment: `.analytics` return is not array. it's ActiveRecord

Answer (score 0):

If the method start with `self.`, it's a Class method, and therefore, must be called upon the class itself.
e.g.
`Analytics.update_analytics(arg1, arg2,...)`
But I'm sure that's not what you want to do.

But `Client.find(xx).analytics` will return an Array. So there is no way your Class method `self.update_analytics` will work on `Client.find(xx).analytics` (which will return an Array).

According to your comments on the first answer, you just want to grab new datas, and update the Client instance. I guess you could do it by making it a module or a service, and give the Client instance as a first argument, and the rest of your other argument after.
That's not a precise answer, but it might give you an idea about how to work your way through your problem.